# Static factory methods and mocking

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, tdd

How do you reconcile using static factory methods and mocking?

Many people would just say: Don't use static factory methods, use DI instead.

Well, sometimes you cannot avoid static factory methods. Consider the following use cases, which should be familiar:

Imagine you have a class called `Option`, like in scala. You can't avoid using a static factory method if you want to reuse same instance for all absent values.

As soon as you go `new Option(null)` you create a new option object, you cannot return the same object over and over again.

Similar use case is the `Integer.valueOf()` which will reuse integer objects for values below 128. Impossible to do without using a static factory method.

Another advantage is that factory methods are more descriptive than `new` keyword.

So how do you guys deal with having to use static factory methods and at the same time wanting to use inheritance and mocks?

Thank you.

Comment: Why would you ever need to `mock` `Option`? `static` factory methods for such trivial classes are fine.

Comment: It's funny that you specifically bring up Scala's `Option` as an example here, since *Scala has no concept of `static` members*. `Option.apply()` is a instance (non-static) method on a normal (instance) object. On the JVM, that instance object is stored in the static field `Option.MODULE`, so calling `Option(1)` actually expands to something like `Option.MODULE.apply(1)`. This is very similar to `System.out.println()`, where `out` is also a static field—but one you can change via `System.setOut()`. In other words, you don't *have* to use static methods for anything...

Answer (score 2):

Since it's a theorical question, I will make a theorical answer. The factory paradigm is the building point for another theory: the Injection. If your created objects are injected when needed, then you only have to inject your mocked objects to do all your tests. There alot of good books / web pages that can help you to get started on that.

Answer (score 2):

Mocking out static methods is possible using [PowerMock](https://github.com/jayway/powermock). Consider the following example from their [Wiki page](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/MockStatic):

```
@Test
public void testRegisterService() throws Exception {
    long expectedId = 42;

    // We create a new instance of test class under test as usually.
    ServiceRegistartor tested = new ServiceRegistartor();

    // This is the way to tell PowerMock to mock all static methods of a
    // given class
    mockStatic(IdGenerator.class);

    /*
     * The static method call to IdGenerator.generateNewId() expectation.
     * This is why we need PowerMock.
     */
    expect(IdGenerator.generateNewId()).andReturn(expectedId);

    // Note how we replay the class, not the instance!
    replay(IdGenerator.class);

    long actualId = tested.registerService(new Object());

    // Note how we verify the class, not the instance!
    verify(IdGenerator.class);

    // Assert that the ID is correct
    assertEquals(expectedId, actualId);
}
```

It's even possible to mock out only one particular method and leave the rest as is, using [partial mocking](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/MockPartial).

Answer (score 1):

My first option is to avoid the need to mock anything, so having static factory methods or not makes no difference.

That said, if I *do* want or need to mock them, then I just do it. For example, consider you are testing a JSF-based web application, and you want to mock the `javax.faces.context.FacesContext` object. I would write the following in a test, using the JMockit library (which I happen to develop):

```
@Test
public void exampleTest(@Mocked final FacesContext ctx) {
    // Call the code under test, which will at some point
    // call FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), then add an
    // error message for display in the web page.

    new Verifications() {{
        FacesMessage msg;
        ctx.addMessage(null, msg = withCapture());

        assertEquals("The expected error message.", msg.getSummary());
        assertNotNull(msg.getDetail());
    }};
}
```

In this example, `Faces.getCurrentInstance()` is the static factory method, which will automatically return a mock `FacesContext` instance once the class is mocked.

Comment: Okay, from what I see you are one of the developers of JMockit, which is admirable, so Kudos for this.  But please understand that others may have different opinions, and please do not get offended by this.  My opinion is that mocks are an awesome practical compromise when there is no other way around them, but the best designed code is code which has no need for mocks.  (Though the first sentence that you wrote appears to anticipate this.)

Answer (score 0):

We simply avoid using static factory methods and we use dependency injection instead.

If java had been designed with DI in mind from the start, then `Integer.valueOf()` would have been:

- `integerType.valueOf()` where `integerType` would be an injected dependency, or
- `typeSystem.getInteger().valueOf()` where `typeSystem` would be an injected dependency, or
- `environment.getTypeSystem().getInteger().getFactory()` where `environment` would be an injected dependency.

There is nothing that you can do with static factories that you cannot do with diligent use of dependency injection.

Now, once someone makes something available only via a static factory method, they are essentially coercing you to take the static road. This is unfortunate.  But you can still wrap the static stuff in instances of your own device, and then inject those instances as dependencies into your production code, and then have your unit tests exercise those instances, avoiding the need to do such ungodly hacks as mocking static methods.

For example, you can wrap `System.out` in some `StandardConsole` object implementing some `Console` interface, and inject that `Console` interface as a dependency into your application.

<sub>(And if you do that, I would even add that you may proceed and configure your version control system to reject any attempts to commit code containing the string "System.out". [evil grin])</sub>

Comment: How would you inject the JSF `FacesContext`, or a Jasper Report´s `JasperRunManager`, which are normally obtained from static factory methods?

Comment: @Rogério easy, create a constructor requirement in the `class` that has a dependency on `JasperRunManager` and tell you DI framework to obtain the instance from the appropriate `static` factory. This is extremely common with Spring, for example` where you can simple annotate a method that returns a call to the `static` factory with `@Bean`.

Comment: @Rogério I amended my answer to address your concern.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Sure, but that fails to account for the fact that's is just simpler & easier to use those APIs (specially `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()`) than to create extra wrapper code with no business value.

Comment: @Rogério it's simpler and easier not to use DI at all and write everything in one very large `main()` method. It has been discovered through painful trial and error however than _simpler and easier_ **now** is sadly very rarely correlated with _simper and easier_ **later**. So your comment is somewhat irrelevant.

Comment: Saying stuff like "ungodly hacks as mocking static methods" sounds to me like a dogmatic mentality, which is not interested in using the right tool for the job.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Actually, it *is* simpler and easier to write object-oriented code, as opposed to procedural-style code full of stateless service "objects" + anemic entities (which, in both cases, are not true objects, as the first lacks state and the second lacks behavior). I speak from my experience in writing OO code since the early 2000's, before DI was the norm.

Comment: @Rogério well, I understand your point.  On the other hand, many people seem to be under the impression that just because there exists a tool that does something which should not normally be done, it is a good idea to go ahead and use that tool so as to allow yourself to do things that should not normally be done.

Comment: So, you are saying that a Java EE developer should *not* use the `FacesContext` API directly? As far as I know, this API is widely used (directly) on modern Java EE apps, and it is going to continue being used. For our own code, which the team controls, naturally you would avoid having static factory methods.

Comment: @Rogério I know nothing about the `FacesContext` API and for this reason I specifically avoided mentioning it.  (Also, others reading this thread might not be familiar with it.)  For the purposes of this discussion I think `System.out` should be a convenient example, since everyone is probably familiar with it.

Comment: `System.out` is a *field*, and a better solution than the one you described (wrapping it in a `Console` abstraction), is to use `System.setOut(PrintStream)` to redirect standard output to an object that can later be inspected in a test. Again, use the right tool for the job; and if it happens to be mocking the factory method, why not? I am not saying anyone should *create* new factory methods if they can avoid them; by all means, use DI or just plain OO code instead.